# Comparar dos Arrays

Tags: c++

El programa consiste en comparar dos arrays para ver si tiene al menos un elemento repetido. El problema esta en la función `mismosElementos`, concretamente en:

```
estaElemento(a[i],b,usados))
```

El error reside en `a[i]`.

> Error: invalid conversion to 'int' to 'const int'

Si le quito la `[i]` el programa funciona, pero solo compararía el primer valor del array `a`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=3;
typedef int tArrayEnt[MAX];
typedef bool tArrayBool[MAX];
void leerArray(tArrayEnt a, tArrayEnt b);
void inicializarBool(tArrayBool usados);
bool mismosElementos(const tArrayEnt a,const tArrayEnt b,tArrayBool usados);
bool estaElemento(const tArrayEnt a,const tArrayEnt b, tArrayBool usados);


int main()
{
    tArrayEnt a,b;
    tArrayBool usados;
    leerArray(a,b);
    inicializarBool(usados);
    if(mismosElementos(a,b,usados))
    {
        cout << "Elementos repetidos";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Elementos no repetidos";
    }
    return 0;
}

void leerArray(tArrayEnt a,tArrayEnt b)
{
    cout << "Introduce los valores del primer array:";
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
       cin >> a[i];
    }

    cout << "Introduce los valores del segundo array:";
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
       cin >> b[i];
    }
}

void inicializarBool(tArrayBool usados)
{
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        usados[i]=false;
    }
}

bool mismosElementos(const tArrayEnt a,const tArrayEnt b,tArrayBool usados)
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<MAX && estaElemento(a[i],b,usados))
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i==MAX;
}

bool estaElemento(const tArrayEnt a,const tArrayEnt b, tArrayBool usados)
{
    int i=0;
    bool encontrado;
    int elemento=a[i];
    while(i<MAX &&(elemento!=b[i] || usados[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
    encontrado=i<MAX;
    if(encontrado)
    {
        usados[i]=true;
    }
    return encontrado;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estás liando.

En `estaElemento` parece que quieres buscar un elemento del array `a` en el array `b`. Así que:

- O bien le pasas el array `a` **y el índice del elemento a buscar**, como `a`
- o bien le pasas **directamente el elemento a buscar**, como `a[i]`.

Lo que tu haces es pasarle el array `a` pero sin índice, así que te inventas uno

```
int i = 0;
...
int elemento = a[i];
```

#### Solución:

O bien pasas directamente el elemento, cambiando la definición (y declaración) de `estaElemento` a

```
bool estaElemento(const int a, const tArrayEnt b, tArrayBool usados);
```

O bien pasas el array i el índice

```
bool estaElemento(const tArrayEnt a, const int indiceElemento, const tArrayEnt b, tArrayBool usados
```